# Do we require webpack for angular universal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack, angular-universal

I am new to angular 2 and created a simple page in angular 2.

Now I want to use server side rendering for my page.I read about angular universal and decided to use it.

But few doubts before starting.
Do we need webpack to implement it.Because i have not used webpack in my application(used basic Quickstart to givven here https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

I tried to use universal but getting some errors so want to confirm.

Please let me know if i can use angular universal without webpack.

Comment: please post what you have tried and what error you are getting.